# CiviXero contact push job fails with throttling error

Tags: civixero

CiviXero has stopped synching since November 2023 and Im trying to run the contact push job but keep getting this error

> Finished execution of CiviXero Contact Push Job with result: Failure,
> Error message: Contact Push aborted due to throttling by Xero

Is there a throttle parameter for the contact push job?

Comment: This throttling limit is set by xero - https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/limits/#api-rate-limits. I think the first job run in a day will still run without limit error and you should be able to see actual error of why contact isn't getting pushed to xero.